# Posting a PHP variable into a bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, php

I've connected to an API with a bash script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl "https://example.com/templates/search?field=template_id&    field=name" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ----------------------------------------------------------------"

curl -X POST "https://example.com/audits" \
-d '{ "template_id": "template_28c5b7ec77f34ea7881b6a9ef9c01b91", "header_items": [ { "item_id": "f3245d40-ea77-11e1-aff1-0800200c9a66", "label": "Audit Title", "type": "textsingle", "responses": { "text": "${title}" } }, { "item_id": "f3245d43-ea77-11e1-aff1-0800200c9a66", "label": "Conducted By", "type": "textsingle", "responses": { "text": "John Citizen" } } ] }' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ----------------------------------------------------------------"
```

This connects successfully.

I then have a PHP webpage with a form in which you can enter a title for the audit. When I press save on the form the script above runs and creates the audit. However, the title is ${title} rather than the value of the textbox.

Is it even possible to post variable values to a bash script in this way?

Comment: Well, the variable is within single quotes, so the shell won't be able to expand it.

Comment: @Kiwy - There's nothing sensitive in my question.

Comment: @Kusalananda - Can you give me an example of what I should be doing please?

Comment: @Kusalanada - SafetyCulture is not my company, anyone can use their API. I removed the authorization code and replaced with dashes already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated with comments and chat discussion taken into account.

The PHP code runs the shell script as `sh ./curl.sh $title` where `$title` is a PHP variable (it should ideally properly quote the `$title` data as to not confuse the shell).  The shell script therefore needs to pick the title from its command line parameters, `$*`, rather than from the shell variable `$title`.

The JSON document that sent is single quoted which means that the variable expansion `$title` will not be seen by the shell.

You need to break out of the single quoted string temporarily to get the variable expanded:

```
-d '{ "template_id": "template...{ "text": "'"$*"'" }...
```

The outer double quotes in `"'"$*"'"` belong to the JSON document, the contents within single quotes belong to the shell. The inner double quotes quotes the `$*` value (in case it contains whitespace and/or filename globbing patterns).

There was an additional issue in the PHP code which meant that the PHP `$title` variable was never set properly. When this was fixed, it worked as expected.

Comment: This doesn't work, the value i'm posting still doesn't become the name of the audit.

Comment: Ok, so there's something I missing then. How are you setting the `$title` shell variable?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $output=shell_exec('sh ./curl.sh $title');
 echo $output;
 }
?>
<?php echo $_GET["title"]; ?>    -- This is what i've got in my PHP file.

Comment: Ah, then you should use `$@` in place of `$title`.  If the title is passed as an command line parameter to the script, it will be available in `$@`. You would still need to use `"'"$@"'"` though.

Comment: This still isn't working?

Comment: @Ross It's difficult to debug blindfolded.

Comment: The above PHP is in the PHP file, this triggers the script in my question. I can't understand what's going wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76951/discussion-between-ross-and-kusalananda).

Comment: This was resolved as the amended answer shows. $title = $_POST["title"];